# While start spring tool suits some error occurs

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-tool-suite

I'm new to spring development. I have downloaded spring-tool-suite-3.6.0.RELEASE-e4.4-win32-x86_64.zip after extracted it. While start STS following error shown add java stopped.

[image: Error Message while start up STS]

Comment: which java version are you using?

Comment: What Java version you are using? Most likely you are using a 32bit version of Java but try to run a 64bit version of STS.

Comment: Java intalled in my sys:
C:\Users\Acer>java -version
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: add to your question: **1)Java version** , **2)STS version** and **3)Operating System details**

Comment: Could this other post help [STS is failing to start on my machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813112/sts-is-failing-to-start-on-my-machine) ?

Comment: I also recommend to set the -vm option in the sts.ini file in order to point it to a full JDK instead of just a JRE.